# Ubuntu 18.04 flask not able to reach api endpoint on port 5000

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am using a Google Cloud Ubuntu 18.04 server and trying to run a flask server.

When I am using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0',8080,debug = False)
```

I am able to hit the API end point using postman.

But When I am trying to use the default 5000 port, I am not able to reach the API endpoint.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run('0.0.0.0',5000,debug = False)
```

I have explicitly used both

```
sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

running

```
netstat -an | grep :5000
```

shows output:

```
tcp  0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Running

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P
```

Shows following output:

```
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r  904 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  17768      0t0  TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
apache2   1156            root    4u  IPv6  19665      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   1157        www-data    4u  IPv6  19665      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   1158        www-data    4u  IPv6  19665      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
sshd      1506            root    3u  IPv4  23628      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1506            root    4u  IPv6  23630      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
python    4088        vineel_k   26u  IPv4  34925      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
```

Are there any other steps that I need to do in order to access the API endpoint using 5000 port?

Comment: The configuration seems correct. But please share some details regarding the VPC network where your VM is hosted on GCP. Are you using the default network? Do you have a [Firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) allowing ingress tcp traffic on port 5000?

Comment: Hi @DanielOcando Thanks for the reply, I didn't know about these settings before, I have asked our administration to set-up the rules for me. I will post the update here once they configure the rule.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOcando, after configuring the Firewall rule on the port, it's working.

Comment: Good to know! I'll add the answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow ingress TCP traffic on the Compute Engine instance's VPC network.